# Change values on y-axis of plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I need the values on the y-axis to start from 0 instead of 5. How do I change this?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $t$,
    ylabel = {\textit{lengte kaars in cm}},
]
%Below the red parabola is defined
\addplot [
    domain=0:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{35- 3*x};
\addlegendentry{$\textit{lengte kaars in cm} = 35 - 3t$}

\addplot[mark=*, color=green] coordinates {(0,35)};

\addplot[mark=*, color=blue] coordinates {(2, 29)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the axes limits.

[image: xx]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = left,
xlabel = $t$,
ylabel = {\textit{lengte kaars in cm}},
ytick={0,5,...,35}, % <<<<<
ymin=0, % <<<<<
ymax=40, % <<<<< +5
xmin=0, % <<<<<
xmax=11, % <<<<< +1 
xtick={0,2,...,10},  % <<<<<
]
%Below the red parabola is defined
\addplot [
domain=0:10, 
samples=100, 
color=red,
]
{35- 3*x};
\addlegendentry{$\textit{lengte kaars in cm} = 35 - 3t$}

\addplot[mark=*, color=green] coordinates {(0,35)};

\addplot[mark=*, color=blue] coordinates {(2, 29)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I expanded the max limits a little for better looking of the head of the arrows.